# Command \iint already defined. Error occurred in color table

Tags: tables, errors, html

I have around 10 colorful tables in my document, but when I created following table I got the error (shown in picture). I applied the available solution on this forum, but its not work. Please guide how I can fix this issue.

My file main.tex has following[image] packages.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
 \geometry{a4paper, margin=1.3in}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

Table Code is here 
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Testing my Table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ID}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pattern}} &
  Very often &
  Often &
  Rarely &
  Sometimes &
  Never \\ \hline
1 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}A &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}38.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}55.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}20.0 \\ \hline
2 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}B &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}48.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}24.0 \\ \hline
3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}C &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}47.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 \\ \hline
4 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}D &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 \\ \hline
5 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}E &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}23.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
6 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}F &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}48.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 \\ \hline
7 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}G &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 \\ \hline
8 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}H &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}24.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 \\ \hline
9 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}I &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}23.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}49.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}33.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 \\ \hline
10 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}J &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 \\ \hline
11 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}K &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}47.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
12 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}L &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}40.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
13 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}M &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}20.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}37.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}40.0 \\ \hline
14 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}N &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
15 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}O &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}37.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}34.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}34.0 \\ \hline
16 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}P &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}40.0 \\ \hline
17 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}Q &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}38.0 \\ \hline
18 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}R &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 \\ \hline
19 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}S &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}46.0 \\ \hline
20 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}T &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
21 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}U &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}43.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}34.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
22 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}V &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}43.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}39.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
23 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}W &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}16.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}33.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}40.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 \\ \hline
24 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}X &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}16.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 \\ \hline
25 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}Y &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}15.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
26 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF}Z &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}14.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your main file looks very convoluted, are you sure you need all those packages?

Comment: That's a lot of packages, but I'd say that the clash is between `amssymb` and `wasysym`.

Comment: `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` appears twice

Comment: Generally, don't load package more than once, especially not with different options.

Comment: I removed the duplicate packages, and also removed the amssymb, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Try loading `wasysym` after `amsmath`.

Comment: the error occurs in the preamble, before your docuemnt has started and is unrelated to tables or color not sure why you mention those in the  title?

Comment: unrelated to the error but don't do `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` to tables you can never get reasonable typographic output if you apply arbitrary scaling like that.

Comment: Are you sure you don't use the `times` option for the document class?

Comment: You're making the table *wider* and so it also becomes taller than the allowed text height. Don't use `\resizebox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue is that you need to load `amsmath` before `amsthm`.  If you do that, the compilation will get far enough to tell you that you left out `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  It will then give you a very confusing error about `\@@scl` being undefined that turns out to trace back to giving `xcolor` an invalid HTML color code.

The larger issue is that you seem to be doing something that a lot of beginners do: copying and pasting code from a lot of existing documents.  Unfortunately, you’ve pasted their preambles together in a way that does not make sense.  You almost certainly don’t need, for example, `lipsum` to insert “Lorem ipsum” dummy text, or to redefine the `geometry` of a journal article.  You no longer need `textcomp` or `inputenc`, since the LaTeX kernel now loads them by default.  Some of the packages you load are redundant, obsolete, or duplicated.

I would clear out the list of packages, then add back the ones your document actually needs, one at a time.

#### Edit

If I add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, then replace the invalid HTML color names, the following document will compile on TeX Live 2020:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table, HTML]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Table Code is here 
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Testing my Table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ID}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pattern}} &
  Very often &
  Often &
  Rarely &
  Sometimes &
  Never \\ \hline
1 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}A &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}38.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}55.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}20.0 \\ \hline
2 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}B &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}48.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}24.0 \\ \hline
3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}C &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}47.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 \\ \hline
4 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}D &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 \\ \hline
5 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}E &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}23.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
6 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}F &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}48.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 \\ \hline
7 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}G &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 \\ \hline
8 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}H &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}24.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 \\ \hline
9 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}I &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}23.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}49.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}33.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 \\ \hline
10 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}J &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}22.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 \\ \hline
11 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}K &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}47.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
12 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}L &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}21.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}40.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
13 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}M &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}20.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}37.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}40.0 \\ \hline
14 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}N &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 \\ \hline
15 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}O &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}37.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}34.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}34.0 \\ \hline
16 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}P &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}19.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}29.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}27.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}41.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}40.0 \\ \hline
17 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Q &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}38.0 \\ \hline
18 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}R &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}27.0 \\ \hline
19 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}S &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}18.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}25.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}46.0 \\ \hline
20 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}T &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
21 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}U &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{70AD47}43.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}34.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
22 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}V &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}17.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}43.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}39.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}26.0 \\ \hline
23 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}W &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}16.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}33.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{A9D08E}40.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 \\ \hline
24 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}X &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}16.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}28.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}44.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 \\ \hline
25 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Y &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}15.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}42.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}36.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}31.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
26 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Z &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}14.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}45.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}35.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}30.0 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}32.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The issue is unrelated to `wasysym`.

I took my best guess which colors you actually wanted when you wrote something that was not a valid HTML color value, but consider using the standard `svgnames` from W3C.

Comment: @campa When I tested on TeX Live 2020, that’s what solved the problem.

Comment: Ah, OK, I've got only TeXLive 2017. Sorry if I have bothered.

Comment: @campa Updated with a version that compiles. The bug turned out to have nothing to do with `wasysym`.

Comment: You should remove `\resizebox`: it should not be used in general, much less in this case where it *widens* the table. Also `\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}` seems really unnecessary.

Comment: @egreg It’s not my code! I made the very minimal changes that got it to compile. You should address your very good points to the OP.

Comment: Thanks , indeed it was issue in HTLM code. Thankful :-)